# How does one remove an async component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that's loaded async via an import handling a click event in a parent component. The parent component listens for a click on a dom element and launches its `this.handleMovieClick(event, 'movie name')` handler.

The parent passes a closeVideo prop to the async loaded child component. In the child component it listens for a click to close the itself or when the video is finished playing. It calls its `this.handleVideoEnd()`, which then calls `this.props.closeVideo`.

The `this.props.closeVideo` goes into the Parent component and calls the parent's `this.handleCloseVideo()`.

My question is how do I remove the async loaded component when it's no longer needed? Right now it is sitting in the DOM. Is there a way of forcing a component to be removed? Is there a way to call `componentWillUnmount` using asyc?

Or is loading component async just useful for code-splitting - load the code that's needed on demand? It's not meant for removing the component from the Parent? But then how does React Router do this?

the Parent Component:

ParentComponent extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
 // bind event handlers
```

// used to hold a reference to the child async loaded component
this.state = {
AnimatedFullScreenMovie: null,
animatedFullScreenMoviePath: null
};

```
  }


handleCloseVideo() {
    this.setState({
      AnimatedFullScreenMovie: null,
      animatedFullScreenMoviePath: null
    })
  }

}

// handles loading the component async, sets the path to movie based on what clicked
handleViewMovieClick(event, name) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.AnimatedFullScreenMovie === null) {
      import('./../../../reusable/AnimatedFullScreenMovie').then(component => 
     {
       if (name === 'movie1') {
          this.setState({
              AnimatedFullScreenMovie: component,
              animatedFullScreenMoviePath: "movie1.mp4"
            });
       } else {
          this.setState({
              AnimatedFullScreenMovie: component,
              animatedFullScreenMoviePath: "movie2.mp4"
            });
       }
     }
  }
```

In the `render()` of the Parent Component:

```
  render() {
// if the this.state.AnimatedFullScreenMovie has a component, render it
const showProfileVideo = () => {
      if (typeof this.state.AnimatedFullScreenMovie !== undefined && this.state.AnimatedFullScreenMovie !== null) {
        const AnimatedFullScreenMovie = this.state.AnimatedFullScreenMovie.default;
        return (<AnimatedFullScreenMovie
          videoSrc={this.state.animatedFullScreenMoviePath}
          closeVideo={this.handleCloseVideo} // <-- pass the handleCloseVideo() as a prop to the async loaded child
        />);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

return(
   <section className="video-slider">
    { showProfileVideo() }
<div>
  <p><a href="#" onClick={() => this.handleViewMovieClick(event, 'movie1')}>Watch the film</a></p>
</div>

<div>    
  <p><a href="#" onClick={() => this.handleViewMovieClick(event, 'movie2')}>Watch the film</a></p>
 </div>
```

);

}

Here is the child Async Component:

```
export default class AnimatedFullScreenMovie extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.videoContainer, this.video;
    this.playVideo = this.playVideo.bind(this);
    this.handleVideoEnd = this.handleVideoEnd.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.video.addEventListener('ended', this.handleVideoEnd);
  }

  playVideo() {
    this.video.play();
  }

  handleVideoEnd() {
    this.video.pause();
    this.props.closeVideo; // <- launch the event handler in the parent to close the video by setting this.state.AnimatedFullScreenMovie to null
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.handleVideoEnd()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.video.removeEventListener('ended', this.handleVideoEnd);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="animated-fullscreen-video-wrapper" ref={videoContainer => this.videoContainer = videoContainer}>
        <h2 onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</h2>
        <video src={this.props.videoSrc} ref={video => this.video = video} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: You should take a look at previous similar asked question about problems unmounting components containing promises. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985738/how-to-unmount-unrender-or-remove-a-component-from-itself-in-a-react-redux-typ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not calling the function properly with `this.props.closeVideo`. The proper way is  `this.props.closeVideo()` in the async child component:

```
export default class AnimatedFullScreenMovie extends Component {

  // previous code

  handleVideoEnd() {
    this.video.pause();
    this.props.closeVideo(); // <- need to have the '()' chars in order to call
  }

 // remainder code


}
```