# React Self Destroying Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a question, how can i unmount component by itself.
so basically, when i click the component it should unmount itself 
without calling the parent component, hide/show properties.
here is a sample of my code.

```
onClose = () => {
    let mountNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(mountNode);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Does it not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unmount, unrender or remove a component, from itself in a React/Redux/Typescript notification message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985738/how-to-unmount-unrender-or-remove-a-component-from-itself-in-a-react-redux-typ)

Comment: Here is the answer, thoughts on this sol'n

  var par = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode;
        par.removeChild(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this) as HTMLElement);

Answer (score 2):

You could store a reference to the node the component is mounted on the component instance <del>returned by `ReactDOM.render()`</del> using a `ref` callback.

```
class Thing extends React.Component {
  onClose = () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.mountNode);
  }
}
const node = document.getElementById("root");
const inst = ReactDOM.render(<Thing ref={(inst) => inst.mountNode = node} />, node);
```

(Edited to use `ref`, cheers @hawk.)

Comment: Why not callback prop?

Comment: i dont want a callback , it's up to the developer if they want a callback or not. just think of a lightbox on jquery.you can subscribe an optional callback for closing or ok button

Comment: but yeah, here is the solution, i need some eyes code review on this.
  var par = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode;
        par.removeChild(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this) as HTMLElement);

Comment: I strongly against modifying the DOM yourself in this case

Comment: @keul, what is your suggestion?